# Magento : Sort bundled products by price

Tags: magento, sorting, product

When I have a category in Magento with bundled products and I sort them by price, the sort order isn't correct.

It seems to sort the products according to the cheapest product in the bundle, instead of sorting it by the cumulative price.

Does anyone have a clue/idea/solution on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Catalog consist of multiple product including **bundle product**.
To ensure the bundle price display correctly 
**app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/Price.php** is injected into magento 1.7.0, so make sure that this page is present in your mage folder.

Also make changes in this section **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/bundle.xml**
as mention in this thread 
https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/bundle.xml#L35
from line 35-117.